# Abrir un modal automaticamente con angular en ng-repat

Tags: angularjs, modal, ng-repeat

tengo la siguiente repeticion:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts" class="modal fade modal-custom " id="myModal[[post.id_post]]" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel[[post.id_post]]" aria-hidden="true">
...
</div>
```

si post.open es igual a 1 quiero que el popup se abra automaticamente, algun tip?

gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Pueden haber múltiples formas, por ejemplo, puedes usar un operador ternario dentro de llaves *`{{}}`* y en caso de ser `true` llamas la función que abre tu modal.

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts" class="modal fade modal-custom " id="myModal[[post.id_post]]" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel[[post.id_post]]" aria-hidden="true">
  {{post.open?miFuncion(aquí_puedo_pasar_valores):'No pasa nada'}}
</div>
```